# How can Place an image in my EMail message

Tags: email, delphi, chilkat-email

I am testing Delphi ChilKat component to send EMail

How can Place an Image as part of my EMail signature, not an attach.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still have to attach the image, but you attach it as a **related item** with a `Content-ID` header assigned to it, not as a normal attachment.  You can then display that image in the email body using an HTML `<img>` tag with a `cid:` url to refer to the image's ID as the image source.

The Chilkat DLL has several `CkEmail_AddRelated...()` functions, and the Chilkat ActiveX object has several `AddRelated...()` methods, for this purpose.

Here are some examples provided by Chilkat (you did not say which Chilkat API you are actually using - the DLL or the ActiveX):

[Email Object Examples for Delphi DLL](https://www.example-code.com/delphiDll/emailObj.asp)

- [(Delphi DLL) Add Base64 Image to HTML Email](https://www.example-code.com/delphiDll/email_add_html_image_from_base64.asp)

[SMTP Examples for Delphi DLL](https://www.example-code.com/delphiDll/smtp.asp)

- [(Delphi DLL) Send HTML Email with Image to iPhone](https://www.example-code.com/delphiDll/smtp_to_iphone.asp)

[Email Object Examples for Delphi ActiveX](https://www.example-code.com/delphiAx/emailObj.asp)

- [(Delphi ActiveX) Add Base64 Image to HTML Email](https://www.example-code.com/delphiAx/email_add_html_image_from_base64.asp)

[SMTP Examples for Delphi ActiveX](https://www.example-code.com/delphiAx/smtp.asp)

- [(Delphi ActiveX) Send HTML Email with Image to iPhone](https://www.example-code.com/delphiAx/smtp_to_iphone.asp)